# Get username from users where id = ".$row['id']."'

Tags: php, mysql

I recently tried to implement this script however I have had some problems with it recently.

```
  $q=mysql_query("select * from users where id='".$row['gamertag']."'");


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($mw2ranks))
{

   echo "<tr><td> ".$i.".";
   echo "</td>
       <td>$q[username]
       </td>
<td>More stuff will go here</td>
<td>More stuff will go here</td>
   ";
   $i++;

}
```

Then I was thinking the code $q[username] would locate the username located in the data match up. This wasn't the case, can anyone tell me why?

Comment: This is a SQL injection waiting to happen!

Comment: Can you provide us more code this will help us to help you.

Comment: Yes, sorry I have put in more code.

Comment: try `$q['username']` instead of `$q[username]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to fetch the result after querying it:

```
$res = mysql_fetch_assoc($q);
```

Note the danger of SQL-injections as mentioned in the comments. also be aware that the MySQL_* methods are deprecated. use PDO instead.

Comment: How can I avoid the SQL injections?

Comment: Although this helped me solve the problem, I'd like to know how to avoid SQL injections as well.

Comment: Read about it everywhere on the web: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), [PHP.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php), [MS TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). Or just [Google](https://www.google.us/#q=sql+injection) for it. You will find plenty of information